# Design api for two roles - patients and doctors

Tags: api, design-patterns, asp.net-core-2.0

I am designing a new web api for my project.

In my app, I have a two roles (patient and doctor). Every user can be assigned to only one role.

Every user has a own profile.

Patient can edit your profile, view, but also view doctor profile.
Doctor the same thing.

How should api looks like?

/api/patient/pro­file
GET: data for view profile

/api/patient/edit-profile
GET: data for edit profile
PUT: edit profile

Doctor will have it the same way.

I want to separate api for both roles.
For patient always: /api/patient
For doctor always: /api/doctor

The problem arises when the doctor wants to read patient data.

/api/doctor/pa­tient/profile?u­serId=xxx

this approach?

Thanks

Backend: Asp Core 2.1
Frontend: React JS

Comment: Doctor should visit `/patient/$PatientID` to view a patient. Making sure doctor has permission to view patientID is your next task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is subjective since there's not one "correct" way to do it, and everyone will have differing opinions. But, there are best practices to follow, and based on the info given, here's how I would approach the URI design for your API.

Patient

```
/api/patients/{id}
/api/patients/{id}/profiles
```

Doctor

```
/api/doctors/{id}
/api/doctors/{id}/profiles
/api/doctors/{id}/patients
/api/doctors/{id}/patients/{patientid}/profiles
```

The authorization for accessing these resources should be handled by [OAuth 2.0 + OpenID](https://oauth.net/2/), using claims and scopes.

Here's a link to some URI best practices - https://blog.restcase.com/7-rules-for-rest-api-uri-design/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using user roles when you authenticate a user for the API.  OAuth 2.0 tokens would be a good choice and just apply scopes to each role.

When someone registers as a patient they have access to certain data and endpoints vs if someone registers as a Doctor. Use the user credential grant to issue an access token, then check scope when a user actually request something.

You could even employ various levels of Doctor permissions that someone could use to help achieve HIPAA compliance if this is being built for doctors in the United States. This way you can show a level of detailed patient information without exposing some medical information.

Podcast explaining OAuth in APIs: http://fullstackradio.com/episodes/4/

There are also quite a few questions and answers in the security part of stackoverlow and stackexchange that go over how to implement roles and scope into your APIs using OAuth.